# Where does 2.3.5 come from and how to prove it?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, proof-explanation

[image]
I was looking over this proof in Atkinson’s Numerical Analysis 2nd Edition and I am having a hard time seeing where 2.3.5 is coming from. What is Atkinson trying to show with 2.3.5 and the line below? Thank you!

Comment: It is not showing, it is defining. All right sides are integer powers of $\delta$, this formula gives a name to that integer. 2.3.6 establishes the integers as Fibonacci numbers.